# Scroll to a particular ID within an iframe while retaining parent page position

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, iframe

I needed to be able to load a particular page in an iframe on demand, so I used a simple wrapper:

```
function updateFrame(url) {
    frames[0].location = url;
}
```

Then I was asked to load the page to a particular point, which was non-trivial, since the pages were not within my control and there weren't always `<a name>` anchors to rely on. So some poking around showed that IDs could be used as anchors.

That is to say, you can scroll to `<div id = "somewhere-down-the-line">` with:

```
updateFrame("http://host/page#somewhere-down-the-line");
```

except this call also scrolls the entire viewport up so that the above `<div>` goes to the top and everything in the parent page above it scrolls out of view.

How do I modify `updateFrame(url)` so that it scrolls the page within the `<iframe>` but leaves the rest of the page as it is?

This hack worked for me on Firefox 20.0.1/Windows. Essentially, I load the page first, then jump to the target:

```
function updateFrame(url) {
    if (url.indexOf('#') > -1) {
        mainPage = url.split('#')[0];
        frames[0].location = mainPage;
    }
    frames[0].location = url;
}
```

I would like to be able to use this in other browsers as well. I have been trying to get it to work in Chrome. Maybe I'll even try Internet Explorer...

Comment: Also, I was wondering since when the IDs became valid anchors. Can't seem to find the W3C recommendation that changed this.

Comment: Is the iframe on the same domain, or could it be a different domain?

Comment: It could be on a different domain. Does that make a difference? I know about CSRF and security measures, but I'm not sure how this may affect the scrolling / refreshing behaviour.

Comment: It doesn't stop scrolling from working, but it does rule out a few ideas I had. The best candidate so far is a nasty hack.

Comment: @JordanGray I've even used `<meta http-equiv = "refresh" content = "0;site#marker">` in an interstitial, but that didn't help matters.

Comment: Argh—I had a go at a rather messier method, but in the end I don't think it's worth it! Too many hacks and probably brittle. Your current solution was my first thought too, for which the credit really goes to @Hashbrown.

Comment: Well @JordanGray, put it up anyway, it's the answer that matters, not the bounty :)

Comment: Haha, I don't mean the bounty—I mean my solution is too messy to be worth you looking at! :) You can see the direction I was going in here: http://jsfiddle.net/Jordan/hxC2R/2/. In short: set the iframe height to its content height, wrap it in a div with `overflow:auto`, and scroll that div to the calculated position of the element. Like I said: messy, and IMO not worth adding an answer.

Comment: Ooh, that does sound convoluted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me on Firefox 20.0.1/Windows. Essentially, I load the page first, then jump to the target:

```
function updateFrame(url) {
    if (url.indexOf('#') > -1) {
        mainPage = url.split('#')[0];
        frames[0].location = mainPage;
    }
    frames[0].location = url;
}
```

On Chrome 28.0/Windows, calling `updateFrame(url)` followed by setting `document.body.scrollTop = 0` (thanks to [this answer](/a/17749326)) had the desired effect, **though only in the console**. I am still testing on other browsers; a more elegant solution is always appreciated :)

As mentioned in the question, though, I would like to be able to use this in other browsers as well. Maybe I'll even try Internet Explorer...

Answer (score 3):

If a hack is ok, and what you're looking for is cross-browser try using [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollTop) to reset where you were.

E.g. if it is the body that scrolls

```js
function updateFrame(url) {
    //save where you were
    var oldScroll = document.body.scrollTop;

    //this moves our body!
    frames[0].location = url;

    //move it back
    document.body.scrollTop = oldScroll;
}
```

Of course if it doesn't actually `scrolls the entire viewport` and instead modifies a parent div or something, the scrollTop property will be on that element too.

Let me know if this works, but screws up the scrolling on the frame, because I can modify this to account for a difference between the two `scrollTop`s

Comment: The `scrollTop` property is correctly identified and shows up in `console.log`, but setting it has no visible effect. The top of the iframe still remains at the top of the page.

Comment: However, setting `scrollTop` outside the function has the desired effect of sending the page back to the top. I'll +1 for reminding me of scrollTop, but this didn't solve the problem the way I wanted it to.

Comment: I probably misunderstood. And there's no way a fiddle would be feasible, so thanks for the +1, I tried :)

Comment: Also, it didn't help in the end. I'd have to manually call `document.body.scrollTop = 0` from the console... somehow including this line in the triggered functions did not scroll anything.

Comment: use `parent.document.body.scrollTop` then, its possible the code is executing in the frame's `window`, not the one we want

Comment: Tried it, it did not work. Thanks for keeping at this though.

Comment: no worries, I'm surprised no-one else has attempted, esp. with a 150rep bounty. But yeah, at least you have a working work around :) its not like you can't go ahead with what you're doing. Have a good one, -Ash

Answer (score 1):

You could try turning the bolts yourself by detecting the height of the element you want, and forcing the [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollTop) of the frame.

```js
function updateFrame(url) {
    //get the parts
    var parts = url.split('#');
    //go to the url
    frames[0].location = parts[0];

    //if there was an anchor
    var anchor;
    if (parts.length > 0 && parts[1].length > 0) {
        //may want to account for a[name="PARTS[1]"] too
        anchor = frames[0].document.getElementById(parts[1]);

        //set the scroll of it yourself, using some sort of library to get "fullTop"
        frames[0].document.body.scrollTop = anchor.fullTop();
    }
}
```

Where `"fullTop"` is equivalent to the distance between the top of the iframe, and the element.
Like jQuery's [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) or YUI's [getXY(el).[1]](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Dom.html#method_getXY)